# creating task in salesforce CRM using createsalesforceobject in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Here is the code... The problem is: 2 similar tasks have been assigned in the salesforce crm.. As i needed a single task to be assigned... Could not find where is the problem ... Please help me with this

```ampscript
 %%[ 
  

var @id,@contactid,@Currentdate,@Clientlastupdated,@Currentdatetimereformatted, @Addtode,@nowGMT



SET @Currentdate = FormatDate(Now(),"YYYY-MM-DD"),
SET @nowGMT = DateAdd(Now(),7,"h")
SET @Currentdatetimereformatted = Format(@nowGMT,"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"),
SET @Currentdatereformatted = Format(@nowGMT,"yyyy-MM-dd"),
SET @accountid = AccountId,
SET @opportunityid = Subscriberkey,



IF _messagecontext == 'SEND' THEN 

SET @id=CreateSalesforceObject('task',8,'WhoId',@contactid, 'WhatId',@opportunityid,
'OwnerId','xxxx',
'CompletedDate__c',@Currentdatereformatted, 
'ActivityDate',@Currentdatereformatted , 
'Subject',emailname_, 
'Status', 'Completed',
'Priority','Medium')


ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: If you could share the issue/problem/error you are facing it would help the community to help easily....  Seems like you are using `@contactid` instead of `@accountid`, as no where you are fetching `@contactid`

Comment: This might be related to the AMPScript being executed two times for Multipart MIME emails. The first time is for the HTML version, and the second time is for the text version. Have you tried removing this code from the text version of the email?

Answer (score 0):

As Rachid pointed out in his answer, this is very likely due to your code being parsed twice, once for HTML, once for text.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/orderOfOperations.html

Solutions:

Option A) manually remove it from Text, but then you have to maintain two code versions as the text version will no longer auto-create from the HTML.

Option B) Understand order of operations and prevent double execution through  an IF-statement.

Make your "problematic" codebit conditional, set the condition to false, and set it to true in the first execution. That way you prevent it from running more than once per user:

```
/*  Workaround for sendouts done using multipart (which is probably 99.9% of times):

HTML is parsed before text.
The IF / else and performNextOccurrence workaround 
helps to prevent that the code in the IF statement is executed twice 
- once in HTML, once in text.

Using this IF statement, 
in the second parsing (the text version)
the variable @performNextOccurrence will be false, 
which skips the conditional code.
*/ 

IF @performNextOccurrence != "false" THEN 

    /* your code here */

    SET @performNextOccurrence = "false" 

ENDIF
```

Comment: How to remove this code from the text version of the email

Comment: @kavya in the editing mode of the email based template, there will be a part call "Plain Text" you can edit from there