# Create new Task in Salescloud using Ampscript Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

When I create a new task using ampscript, a Task is created but 2 tasks are creating at a time.
here is the code

```
SET @id=CreateSalesforceObject('task',7,'WhatId',@opportunityid, 'OwnerId',@ID,'CompletedDate__c',@Currentdatereformatted,
'ActivityDate',@Currentdatereformatted, 'Subject',emailname_, 'Status', 'Completed','Priority','Medium')
```

Comment: Are you doing this from an email or a CloudPage?

Comment: Please do check this... **Rachid** has already answered the reason https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389093/creating-task-in-salesforce-crm-using-createsalesforceobject-in-mc ...... try removing the AMPscript from the `Text-version` of your email.

Comment: From an Email @zuzannamj

Comment: In that case check @VishalKumarCV’s comment above

Comment: Worked Thank You